# Speed Up Query to Delete Duplicate Records but Retain One

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of c6m records. The id field is the unique primary key but MName, SName and Date/Time are not unique.

I want to delete all duplicate records whilst retaining one. The query below takes several hours to run on a reasonably powerful PC. Is there a quicker/more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

```
DELETE t1 FROM r.test t1, r.test t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.MName = t2.MName AND t1.SName = t2.SName AND t1.`Date/Time` = t2.`Date/Time`
```

Comment: you can try adding index  on **MName, SName** to speed up the query,

Comment: You really created a column named  `Date/Time`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql